# UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext with CALayers

Tags: objective-c, cashapelayer, quartz-core

I am trying to create an image of a `UIView` with `CALayer` sublayers. With this code

```
- (UIImage*)snapshot{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);
    [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return viewImage;
}
```

I get an image, but it doesn't accurately represent what is displayed on the screen. In particular, it does not respect the `CAShapeLayer` mask property. My rounded corners don't appear in the image.

Here is a comparison of how an example appears on the screen to how it appears in the image:
[image]

Just to clarify, the image on the right is placed in the same position as the old object, basically rasterizing the object. That is why there is the same background; it is not part of the object that I'm capturing the image of.

How can I capture an image of the object while retaining the `CAShapeLayer` mask in the image?

EDIT: It seems it was the layer mask that was the problem, not the path.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `self.bounds.size` and `self.layer`, just use that view whose corner is rounded.
suppose if it is `imageView` then

```
- (UIImage*)snapshot
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageview.size);
    [imageview.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return viewImage;
}
```

Comment: The view contains many subclassed UIButtons as subviews. These UIButton subclass objects contain multiple CAShapelayers as sublayers. It is these CAShapeLayers that contain the rounded corners. How could I do this without capturing each and every CALayer as a separate image?

Comment: This really doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Straight from the CALayer Class reference:

> Additionally, layers that ... specify backgroundFilters, filters, compositingFilter, or a **mask** values ... are not rendered.

I'm using a mask, not a CGPath. (Well, a CALayer with a path is my mask, but still.)

Another problem, however, is I cannot switch to using a path instead of a mask, because I am using gradients and CAGradientLayer does not have a path property like CAShapeLayer, which is why I used a mask.